# URL not executed in file_get_contents();

Tags: php, url

I need to execute a URL in back-end, when ever the page executes, for this I am using `file_get_contents();` but sadly it is not processing the `url` requested, please help me, pardon me if I am wrong, thank you.

**.PHP**

```
<?php
$url="http://www.foo.in/bound/bound.php?phone_no=".$from_id."&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &bound_version=2&extra_data=<response><dial record='true' limittime='1000' timeout='30' moh='default' >".$to_id."</dial></response>";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: What is the result of $data ?

Comment: some sites blocks request by file_get_contents() because you need set some headers, use CURL

Comment: @Hari: Check in your php.ini so `allow_url_fopen` is set to on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved out the solution there was a gap in URL there was space after api_key and extra_data not encoded, btw thanks for support.

**.PHP**

```
$url="http://www.foo.in/bound/bound.php?phone_no=".$from_id."&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=2&extra_data=".urlencode("<response><dial record='true' limittime='1000' timeout='30' moh='default' >".$to_id."</dial></response>");

$data = file_get_contents($url);

echo $data;
```